# issue with adding datetimepicker in dynamically added table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am working on a project where I am finding difficulty in adding datetimepicker to dynamically added table rows. I have added datetimepicker to static table rows and it is working fine for them but not working for dynamically added table rows.

The tutorial I am following for datetimepicker

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

My Code I tried: I am cloning hidden rows.

Row Clone function:

```
  // Table Add Function
  $('.table-add').click(function () {

    var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');            
    hid = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').attr('id');
    // //Assigning every table row a unique ID
    var max=0;
    $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
        var id=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        if (id>=max){
           max = id;
         }
     });

     //cloning row with new ID  
     $clone.attr('id', parseInt(max)+1);
     //always assign new id to new table row, will be easy to recognize rows
     $clone.find('input.myinput').attr('id', parseInt(max)+1);

     $clone.find("[name='datepicker']").datetimepicker();
     //$("[name='datepicker']").datetimepicker();

     $hiddentr = $('table').find('tr.hide');

     //add dynamic word picker to cloned rows dynamically
     $clone.find('td:nth-last-child(4)').after('{% if obj.word_picker == "Y" %} <td><input id="wordpicker" style="border:none"; data-role="tagsinput" class="myinput" name="unique_tag"/></td>{% endif %}');
     $clone.appendTo( $('#'+hid).parent());
     //submitting form after row clone
     submitForm();
  });
```

HTML of hidden td:

```
<td> 
   <div style="position: relative"> 
     <input class = "form-control" type= "text" name = "datepicker" id= "datetime">
   </div> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Messy but just init datetimepisker each time after you add a row...

`$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();`

`$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();`

etc

Answer (score 0):

I was able to initialize the datetimepicker once the element was completely generated into the dom. [working codepen](https://codepen.io/rfletcher-CodePassion/pen/JBPxWy)

```
  function addTableRow() {  

  var tbodyElement = document.getElementById("tbody");  
  var trElement = document.createElement("tr");

  trElement.id = "generatedTr";

  for (var x=0; x<3; x++) {
      var tdElement = document.createElement("td");  
      var textNode = document.createTextNode("Generated td: " + x);
      tdElement.appendChild(textNode);      
      trElement.appendChild(tdElement);
  }

  var finalTdElement = document.createElement("td");  
  var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
  inputElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
  inputElement.id = "generatedInput";  
  finalTdElement.appendChild(inputElement);
  trElement.appendChild(finalTdElement);  
  tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement);  

  $('#generatedInput').datetimepicker();
}
```

If you have multiple elements that are being generated that needs the datetime picker, then I would suggest creating a class on all of them, then simply instantiate the plugin against that class like so.

```
  $('.dateTimePickers').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: try adding the datepicker to the hidden element first, when you clone your table because you are using .clone(true) it should also grab the event handlers associated once the hidden element is initialized first.

I suspect that your event handlers aren't binding because it doesn't exist in the dom at that point. (others please correct me if I'm wrong). I'll quickly try it out in my code pen by cloning the entire panel once I get in front of my PC again

Comment: ah disregard previous comment, testing showed that the cloned event handlers still point to the original table. Not the cloned state.

After your table has been cloned, you'll have to target the input field and initialize the datetimepicker once it's hit the dom. That should work AFTER the table clone has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest don't initialize the datetimepicker every time after each element. better use following code. It will work like a charm.

I have been doing lot of research for this. Thus, Recommending to use Following code.

```
$('body').on('focus',".datetimepicker", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```